# Attribute error whenever I import matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

Everytime I import matplotlib into my python programs I get this error (here the program is just one line "import matplotlib.pyplot as plt"):

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):   
File "string.py", line 1, in \<module>  
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt   
File "D:\Other programs\Python38\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 94,
 in \<module>      
 import logging   
File "D:\Other programs\Python38\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 28, in \<module>    
     from string import Template   
File "D:\programs\python\string.py", line 1, in \<module>    
     import matplotlib.pyplot as plt   
File "D:\Other programs\Python38\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 36, in \<module>    
import matplotlib.colorbar   
File "D:\Other programs\Python38\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\colorbar.py", line 40, in \<module>    
import matplotlib.artist as martist   
File "D:\Other programs\Python38\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 17, in \<module>    
_log = logging.getLogger(__name__)   
AttributeError: partially initialized module 'logging' has no attribute 'getLogger' (most likely
 due to a circular import)
```

I cannot find any logging.py anywhere. Is this some sort of bug in the lates version of matplotlib?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your script `D:\programs\python\string.py`, where you try to `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` is named `string.py` and it interferes with `string` module from standard library. Rename that file.